# How can I handle click on some items inside a row of RecyclerView?

Tags: android

I want to add a popup menu when I click on the dots inside a RecyclerView row, this menu will show many options include (delete, update and more) and want to do the logic of this popup menu outside the adapter activity not inside it.
How can I do it?

[image: this is the pic of what I want to do]

here is my Adapter Code

```
public class JobAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<JobAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private List<JobModel> mData;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private JobAdapter.ItemClickListener mClickListener;
// data is passed into the constructor
public JobAdapter(Context context, List<JobModel> mData) {
    this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.mData = mData;
}
// inflates the row layout from xml when needed
@NonNull
@Override
public JobAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.job_item, parent, false);
    return new JobAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
}
// binds the data to the TextView in each row
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final JobAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.Name.setText(mData.get(position).getName());
    holder.HeadLine.setText(mData.get(position).getHeadLine());
    holder.Time.setText(mData.get(position).getTime());
}
// total number of rows
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mData.size();
}
// stores and recycles views as they are scrolled off screen
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener {
    TextView Name;
    TextView HeadLine;
    TextView Time;
    View MyJobOptions;
    ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        Name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.employer_name);
        HeadLine = itemView.findViewById(R.id.head_line);
        Time = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_of_job);
        MyJobOptions = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewOptions);
        // these are used when the click on the whole view not on item inside view
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
        MyJobOptions.setOnClickListener(this); // new
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (mClickListener != null) {
            mClickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
            //    mClickListener.onMyJobOptionsClick(view, getAdapterPosition()); // new
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
        if (mClickListener != null) mClickListener.onItemLongClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
        return true;
    }
}
// convenience method for getting data at click position
JobModel getItem(int id) {
    return mData.get(id);
}
// allows clicks events to be caught
void setClickListener(JobAdapter.ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
    this.mClickListener = itemClickListener;
}
// parent activity will implement this method to respond to click events
public interface ItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    void onItemLongClick(View view, int position);
    //   void onMyJobOptionsClick(View view, int position); //new
}
```

}

Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Inside the class viewholder you have a view, you can access the elements of the item with the itemView. it would be something like this:

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener {
YourInterface interface;
TextView Name;
TextView HeadLine;
TextView Time;
View MyJobOptions;
ViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    Name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.employer_name);
    HeadLine = itemView.findViewById(R.id.head_line);
    Time = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_of_job);
    MyJobOptions = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewOptions);
    // these are used when the click on the whole view not on item inside view
    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    MyJobOptions.setOnClickListener(this);


    itemView.findViewById(R.id.TheITEMTHATYOUWANTOCLICK).setOnClickListener{

     interface.yourMethod()
    }
}
```

In Activity

```
class YourActivity implements YourInterface{
override void yourMethod(){
//the logic of what you want to be done
}


}
```

In Interface

```
public interface YourInterface{
void yourMethod()
}
```

Let me know if it works for you!

Comment: I want to perform the code of the popup menu in other activity not inside adapter

Comment: for that you can implement an interface that the activity will implement and the viewholder will use. I'll update the answer